# Triangle T has vertices (0, 2), (0, 7) and (k, 1). Matrix is used to transform T to Tʹ. If the area of Tʹ is 165, determine the value of k.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

The solutions for this question can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NvXC.jpg

I don't understand how the solutions knew that the transformation matrix was what it has stated above. How did they get \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 \\
-2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of the matrix is $11$. That is the number you need to multiply the original area by to get the area of the new triangle. So the area of the original triangle is $165/11= 15$. On the other hand it is $5\cdot k/2$ ($1/2$ base times hight). so $k=6$.

Comment: I understand that the area of the new triangle is determinant of transformation matrix * original area. But i don't know where to get the translation matrix from, and therefore i do not know how to get the determinant. The original question did not provide the diagram or the translation matrix it was just: Triangle T has vertices (0, 2), (0, 7) and (k, 1). Matrix is used to transform T to Tʹ. If the area of Tʹ is 165, determine the value of k.

Comment: If you do not know anything about the linear map this question has no answer. I guess the formulation gives enough info to reconstruct the matrix. What you need is images of two nonparallel  vectors.

Comment: As far as I can tell the image in your post does not have a formulation of the problem. What is the exact formulation?

Comment: What do you mean by formulation? The actual question it self was, Triangle T has vertices (0, 2), (0, 7) and (k, 1). Matrix is used to transform T to Tʹ. If the area of Tʹ is

165, determine the value of k.

Comment: That question has no answer because the matrix is not given. It may be a typographical error